# Vertical align of label in Angular MatButtonToggle

Tags: angular, angular-material

here is the issue: the labels of my Material toggle buttons are not vertical aligned. I need to increase button size and font

**HTML**

```html
<mat-button-toggle-group name="fontStyle" aria-label="Font Style">
  <mat-button-toggle value="bold">Bold</mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle value="italic">Italic</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

**CSS**

```css
.mat-button-toggle {
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 64px;
  background-color: #616161;
  color: #e0e0e0;
  font-size: 32px;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.mat-button-toggle-checked {
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 32px;
}

.mat-button-toggle-group {
  border: none;
  height: 64px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried applying the vertical-align property? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Answer (score 0):

You need to change line-height as well:

```
.mat-button-toggle {
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-right:8px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 64px;
  line-height: 64px;
  background-color:  #616161;
  color: #e0e0e0;
  font-size: 32px;
  padding:0 !important;
}
```